# Why def affects numerics precision promotion in Clojure 1.2?

Tags: clojure

Consider this:

```
user=> (let [i Integer/MAX_VALUE] (+ i i))
java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
user=> (def i Integer/MAX_VALUE) 
#'user/i
user=> (+ i i)
4294967294
```

Why with `let` precision promotion does not happen and we get overflow exception, but with `def` precision promotes to `Long`? Is it a bug?

Comment: I do not see that behavior on my setup. What is your Clojure and Java version?

Comment: The error is specific to Clojure 1.2.1 and below, and does not appear in 1.3 and up. Clojure 1.2.1 is close to 3 years old. If you can, consider upgrading.